# grep: input file 'X' is also the output

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line, grep, io-redirection

I use `ubuntu 14.4`, and been attempting to redirect the output of `grep` command to a file, but I keep getting this error:

`grep: input file 'X' is also the output`

I run the following command:

```
grep -E -r -o -n r"%}(.*){%" > myfile
```

As the error states, it seems that somehow it's interpreting the input and output as same name/obj. I searched but couldn't find what exactly is the problem?!

Comment: If you are trying `grep pattern file > file` then it doesn't work. You cannot use the same file as input and output for grep.

Comment: i add my command ! thanks for hint , but when i try to use a file in other path the does not predicate it and i cant do that !

Comment: for example with ../f i get this `bash: ../f.txt: Permission denied`

Comment: show full command, what is your input file, or are you using the pipe?

Comment: Yes, please show the entire command. It's unclear what you're asking us at this point, so unlikely that anyone will be able to help you further.

Comment: @jimmij hey, thanks for your hint , i do it whit `grep -E -r -o -n "%}(.*){%" >> /home/user_name/Desktop/a.txt
`

Comment: @jimmij please add your command as an answer ! i think its deserved to approved !

Comment: Now I understand that you are actually greping recursively the whole directory structure and want to append the result to the file which already exists in this structure. The problem is that shell (bash, zsh, whatever) **first** performs redirections and only then goes back to commands (grep in this example). It means that `grep` in command `grep pattern file > file` sees already empty file, so has nothing as input. However if you use `>>` instead of `>` then the file is not empty, but grep throws error anyhow as it may lead to recursive processing the same line (pattern) over and over again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not possible to use the same file as input and output for `grep`.
You may consider the following alternatives:

- temporary file

  ```
  grep pattern file > tmp_file
  mv tmp_file file
  ```
- sed

  ```
  sed -i -n '/pattern/p' file
  ```
- put whole file in the variable (not bright idea for large files)

  ```
  x=$(cat file); echo "$x" | grep pattern > file
  ```

Comment: **sed** can be more portable
`sed -i '/pattern/!d' file`

Comment: But in the case OP wants `sed -i -n 's/.*\(pattern\).*/\1/p' file`

Comment: @Costas you are right, the question was edited and additional info added so one can polish `sed` syntax as well.

Comment: Why exactly it is not possible to use the same file as input and output for `grep`?

Comment: @pmor Because shell first takes care of redirections and only then executes the commands, so the file will be truncated by the time `grep` connects it as an input.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `--exclude` field in your `grep` command like so:

```
grep  --exclude=myfile  -Eron  r"%}(.*){%"  >  myfile
```

Comment: Make sure `myfile` is unique as it only applies to the file's basename. You don't want to skip files with the same name in other directories.

Comment: This answer better fits the original question, which involved file tree recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do this

```bsh
echo "$(grep pattern file)" > file
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `find` and GNU `grep` (as found on Ubuntu), you could do:

```
find . -type f ! -samefile myfile \
  -exec grep -Hon 'r%}(.*){%' {} + > myfile
```

Or to also look in symlinks to regular files (like some `grep`s do with `-r`):

```
find -L . '(' ! -xtype l -o -prune ')' ! -samefile myfile -type f \
  -exec grep -Hon 'r%}(.*){%' {} + > myfile
```

`! -samefile myfile`  will make sure `myfile` or any hardlink (or symlink in the one with `-L`) to it is not included in the list of files `grep` will look in.

Another option is to use `moreutils`'s `sponge`:

```
grep -Hon 'r%}(.*){%' . | sponge myfile
```

`sponge` will delay writing to the file until eof on its stdin, so until `grep` has finished (note however that to do that, it stores the whole input in memory).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way in bash:
`cat >> IN_OUTPUT_FILE <<< "$(grep something IN_OUTPUT_FILE)"`

The command in `<<<"..."` will be executed first.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `grep` will continue to look into that folder after the creation of `myfile`.

You can simply give it another path:

```
grep -E -r -o -n r"%}(.*){%" > /tmp/myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `tee` instead of redirecting:

```
grep pattern file | tee file
```