# Search for string(s) in files and report four lines of context (match and three following)

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a string (or a list of strings) that is/are to be searched in all the files of a directory.  For example, if I am searching for ABC, and `file1.txt` contains ABC on line 6, then I want lines 6, 7, 8, and 9 from that file. 
I want all such output to go to a new output file.

Comment: Please expand the question to include an example.

Comment: For E.G: string=ABC, directory=DIR1(contains huge text files). i want to search 'ABC' in all the files of directory 'DIR1'. suppose if we have ABC string in 6th line of file1.txt means i need 6,7,8,9 to be copied to output file. This is simple example. but i have big list to be searched.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this suits.  Makes use of the `grep -A` (after-context) option, to output  the matching line and the 3 subsequent lines.

```
find . -name file\* -exec grep -A 3 ABC {} \; > result-filename
```

**NOTE:** You shouldn't place `result-filename` in `directoryname`. (See: [grep: input file 'X' is also the output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164236/grep-input-file-x-is-also-the-output)).

To cover multiple patterns:

```
find . -name file\* -exec egrep -A 3 'ABC|XYZ' {} \; > result-filename
```

Or multiple patterns from a file (thanks Evgeny Vereshchagin) :

```
find . -name file\* -exec grep -A 3 -f patterns.txt {} \; > result-filename
```

Comment: Instead of single string, If i have list of strings. how can i perform ?

Comment: put your strings in file `patterns` (one string per line) and run `find dir -type f -exec grep -A 3 -f patterns {}  \; >result`

Comment: (1) +1 for `grep -A`.  (2) Why are you suggesting **`-name file\*`** as part of your answer?  The filename `file1.txt` was just an example; the OP never said that he’s looking for files *whose names begin with `file`*.  Perhaps you meant `-type f`?  (3) Why not just say `grep -A 3 -f patterns.txt *`?  The question is imprecise regarding the meaning of “all the files of a directory”.  If you need to include “hidden” files, use `shopt -s dotglob`.  If you need to recurse into subdirectories, say `shopt -s globstar` and use `grep … **`.

Comment: (3) Didn't like the `grep -A 3 -f patterns.txt *` as it would prefix each line with the filename and also include an occasional `--`

Answer (score 1):

The following will search all not-dot files in the current directory:

```sh
sed '/string/{
        $!N;$!N;$!N;$!N
        w ./new_out_file
     }' ./*
```

To do multiple `-F`ixed-*`string`* matches with `grep -A` w/o `find` and w/o the filenames prepended to each match, you just first need a single stream.

```sh
cat ./* | grep -A2 -Ff pattern_file >outfile
```

Comment: Thanks ... but if i have list of names to searched in files of a directory and  need same 4 lines from its occurrence to copied to output.   How it gonna help ??

Comment: @PraveenKashekar   I don't know what this means. This is an answer to the question you asked.

Answer (score -1):

I got solution for it:

```
grep -A 2 -f 'INPUT.txt' *.* >> RESULT.txt
```

Comment: That prepends the filename in which each match is found to the matched lines. That's nothing like what is requested in your question.